# what has replaced UITableViewCell setText now that setText is deprecated?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, methods, deprecated

iPhone OS 3.1.2, older program uses UITableViewCell.text, which is now deprecated.  Does anyone know what the new Setter is supposed to be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The setter is: `[cell.textLabel setText:@"Text"]`